# javascript/jquery in modx

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, modx

i'm developing a website and am trying to integrate a code in my template. But when I integrated the code, the website went blank and just give me white background. The contents were gone.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
{{head}}
<body class="home">
{{skip-links}}
<div class="page_margins">
  <div class="page">
    {{header}}
    {{main-nav}}

    <!-- begin: main content area #main -->
    <div id="main">

        <!-- begin: #col2 second float column -->
        <div id="col2">
            <div id="col2_content" class="clearfix">

                <!--{{news-box}}-->               
               <!-- {{events-box}}-->
                {{eventsdebox}}
                {{articles-box}}
                {{success-box}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: #col2 -->

        <!-- begin: #col3 static column -->
        <div id="col3">
            <!--<div id="col3_content" class="clearfix">
                <div id="home">
                    <div id="home">
                        <p class="float_left"><a href="[~399~]">w4</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="home">
                        <p class="float_right"><a href="[~5~]">product</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>-->
                <div id="tintin">&nbsp;</div>

                <div class="image" style="background-image:url('pic007s.jpg');">
                <div style="left:25px; top:180px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 1</a> </div>
                <div style="left:30px; top:80px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 2</div>
                <div style="left:60px; top:30px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 3</div>

                <div style="right:60px; top:30px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 4</div>
                <div style="right:40px; top:80px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 5</div>
                <div style="right:20px; top:180px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 6</div>

                <div style="right:40px; top:250px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 7</div>
                <div style="right:75px; top:300px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 8</div>

                <div style="left:80px; top:300px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 9</div>
                <div style="left:50px; top:250px"><a href="http://www.web.com/en/solutions">Text 10</div>



               {{teaser-box}}
        </div>
            <!-- IE column clearing -->
            <div id="ie_clearing">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>                
        <!-- end: #col3 -->
    </div>
    <!-- end: #main -->

    {{footer}}
  </div>
</div>
<!-- full skiplink functionality in webkit browsers-->
<script src="assets/templates/ourtemplate/yaml/core/js/webkit-focusfix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; class=MsoNormal; charset=iso-8859-1"/> 
</html>
```

Comment: It probably isn't the problem, but that meta tag at the end should be in the <head>.

Comment: @paulmoriss:what do you mean?

Comment: @paulmorris: I did that but it is still the same.

Comment: When the {{head}} is filled in on the real page is there a <head>....</head> section?

Comment: Also can you give a link to the real page? It's hard to work out what's going on without knowing what your webkit-focusfix.js script does.

Comment: @paulmorris: No there is no <head> ... </head> in the template. By the way, I see that I have 4 templates. And this is the main one. Here is the link: www.wikima4.com

Comment: That page isn't blank. Which is the blank page you have the problem with?

Comment: @paulmorriss: I did it locally. I didn't test it live

Comment: @paulmorris:I'm using XAMPP when I did it. I copied the jquery code and then all I got is a white page. Any idea what is happening? Do I have to install something?

Comment: you even did't closed the body tag

Comment: I just want to point out that you don't need a XAMPP server to run jQuery code, seeing as it is client executed code. Also, your tagging is an absolute mess, you need to add all the chunk code into the document, so we can actually see what is going on. You might want to go read up about html tags as well, seeing as that could be one of your problems.

Comment: If you ever figured out your problem, you should add it, and close it!

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- Try clearing the global cache, log out of the manager and clear your browser cache.
- Could be that you have an incorrectly formatted line of PHP code that
  makes MODx produce a completely blank page. Review your snippets & plugins! (Even 3rd party plugins could have errors). Here's a [php checker tool](http://phpcodechecker.com/).
- Check permissions. Make sure elements can be read/loaded by the user.
- Check the server logs for issues and run phpinfo to make sure all is well setup.